# How can I solve error in teamcity (Nunit)?

Tags: nunit, teamcity

Recently our NUnit build configuration has occasionally stopped halfway through the tests, but the overall build outcome is successful . When I look at the build log, the last test that actually got executed shows:

> Process exited with code -100 (Step: tests (NUnit))

and then the build stops. Under "Failure Conditions". Our NUnit Consol is 3.10.0 .

Below is our NUnit configuration image.

[image: NUnit configuration]

Comment: the error message is as follows: An exception occurred in the driver when loading tests

Answer (score 0):

I've found [this comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-56758#focus=streamItem-27-3060430.0-0) in the TeamCity YouTrack. Seems, dotnet projects aren't supported in NUnit build step.

Try to use .NET CLI build step with "dotnet test" command to run tests in this project. Does it work?